# Gitlab Ci not always getting latest version of dependency

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Background: Gitlab 13.4 building/deploying Java Tomcat application using Maven using two runners (on the same machine)

Project A is the web application and buils/deploys a war file.  it depends on Project B
Project B is a set of dependencies as a jar file

the .gitlab_yml file for project B kicks off a build/deploy of Project A after the 'deploy' stage is completed.

The problem is that Project A doesn't reliably have the latest version of the project B jar file

Comment: Are you collecting war file as an artifact of project A?

Answer (score 0):

i updated the mvn command to include -U to force a retrieve all resources